# What tools does Stack Exchange have to promote sites within Stack Exchange

Tags: support, beta-phase, site-promotion

We are having difficulty attracting some attention to out site [CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) to draw some answers.

I have been placing bounties, and the last one went unanswered. [This one](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) has gotten about 6 views since it had a bounty placed on it. I only made it small, as I don't want to keep tossing away rep.

I notice there are blogs and podcasts that mention various Stack Exchange sites.

How can we ask for some mention in some of these things?

Comment: Not sure if it applies for CogSci, but if there's a more popular site that has some questions that are on topic for your site, you can try to steal them, either officially with Meta discussions and flagging for migration (although it's in Beta, so migration may not work), or simply linking to the site on the question.

Comment: @Dukeling yes, I try to do that.. did that with [Philosophy.se], which is also a bit slow lol And i come here hoping someone new might go, wow just up my alley lol cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing a bounty really only exposes a question to people who are already on your site.  Getting mentioned on the Stack Exchange blog or podcast might help a little bit, but if people already participating in the SE network were interested in your site's topic, odds are they'd already be on your site.

If you want to attract attention outside the Stack Exchange network, it's really up to your community to do that.  The blog posts [Own Your Community](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/own-your-community-2/) and [Helping The Experts Get Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/) outline some strategies that can help attract new users to your site.

Comment: We also run some house ads for beta sites across the network, though I'm not sure off the top of my head what the selection criteria for those is, and place questions in the "hot" tab in the supercollider. The latter definitely does nothing for questions that aren't otherwise already popular somehow.

Comment: @AnnaLear yeh, and it would have to be a really interesting Q, Pets is a better site for drawing in people for a look..